# Make simple js fiddle animation start on button click instead of page load.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jsfiddle

I found this rather cool Js fiddle and have been editing the animation a bit and think its something I can use on a current project. However im not the best with Javascript. All I really need to know to accomplish the rest of my goal is how to make the animation not start until you click a button.

Here is the animation for the js fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/apipkin/qUTwQ/

Here is the css.

```
#o { 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 400px; 
    position: relative; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;}

  .bubble { 
    border: 1px solid 
    #f40009; display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    border-radius: 20px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 20px; 
    }
```

The rest is in the JS fiddle.

Thanks fo any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wrap it in a function and call that function on click.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qUTwQ/307/)</kbd>

Create a button:

```
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

And this js:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', startAnimation);
function startAnimation() {
YUI().use('node', 'anim', 'anim-node-plugin', function(Y) {

    var o = Y.one('#o'),
        oW = o.get('offsetWidth'),
        oH = o.get('offsetHeight'),
        max = 12,
        min = 4,
        bubbles = 20,
        timerDelay = 4000;


    function makeBubble() {
        var b = Y.Node.create('<span class="bubble"></span>');

        b.plug(Y.Plugin.NodeFX, {
            duration: 7,
            easing: Y.Easing.easeOut,
            to: {
                top: 0,
                opacity: 0
            },
            on: {
                end: function() {
                    Y.later(10000, this, function(){
                    animBubble(this.get('node'));
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        o.append(b);
        animBubble(b);
    }

    function animBubble(b) {
        var v = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

        b.setStyles({
            height: v + 'px',
            width: v + 'px',
            borderRadius: v + 'px',
            top: (oH + 2) + 'px',
            opacity: 1
        });

        b.setStyle('left', Math.floor(Math.random() * (oW - v)));

        b.fx.set('duration', Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 3));
        b.fx.set('to.top', Math.floor(Math.random() * (oH / 2)));


        b.fx.run();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < bubbles; i++) {
        Y.later(Math.random() * timerDelay, this, function() {
            makeBubble();
        });
    }

});
}
```